# Is it possible to build across all selected buildings simultaneously?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to build across all selected buildings simultaneously? Instead of having to click marine 5 times to build at 5 rax to build at all 5 in 1 command. I've tried variations of holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and haven't seem to find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not exactly what you want, but you can also hold down the hotkey, and it will rapidly queue up build orders. It can be pretty handy for things like morphing a lot of banelings.

Comment: This is alot closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: my friend was amazed to see my apm spike in a replay.  i suspect it was when i was morphing 50 banelings by holding down the e key :)

Answer (score 3):

StarCraft II has a new model where you tell it exactly how many things you want. If you want 5 marines, you press "Marine" 5 times. If you have 10 corrupters selected, and you want 4 brood lords, press Brood Lord 4 times. It is a little annoying at first, but is vastly superior. Imagine you've got 3 larvae selected. You can press "drone", "zergling", "overlord" and it will build one of each. Very handy.

Comment: The hotkey for marine is actually a, not m.

Comment: -1 this is exact opposite of what I asked for, while I understand the reasoning of not automatically multiplexing your command across all structures the fact is there should be a way to do so by holding a function key and sending your build command.